# Capturar as horas na biblioteca fullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

bom dia!

Estou trabalhando com a biblioteca fullCalendar, e gostaria de ajuda no momento de capturar as horas quando clicado em um determinado intervalo.

Estou conseguindo pegar a data de boas, o problema é só com as horas.

```
dayClick: function(start, end, allDay) {
   start = $.fullCalendar.formatRange(start, start, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
},
```

Desde já, agradeço pela atenção!

Answer (score 2):

Olá, tudo bem?

Antes de mais nada o evento 'dayClick' é disparado quando uma data do calendário é clicada e não um evento do calendário.

Outra coisa que percebi é que os parâmetros do método estão bem diferentes dos parâmetros da documentação. Note: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/

Se o seu problema for um evento utilize o método 'eventClick'.
Segue o link da documentação https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Aqui um exemplo de como você pode fazer utilizando tanto o event disparado clicando em um dia do calendário quanto o event disparado clicando em um evento do calendário.

```
        $('#calendar-container').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev, next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay'
        },
        locale: 'pt-br',
        defaultDate: '2016-12-19',
        navLinks: true,
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, 
        events: events,
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
            console.log("Clicou no dia: " + date.format());
        },
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
            console.log("Clicou no evento: " + calEvent.title);

            // Marco o evento clicado
            $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

            if(calEvent.url){
                // Ativar um modal aqui

                // Cancelo o evento
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade stackoverlow em português. Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência. Como por exemplo, como realizar esta implementação.

Comment: Melhorei minha resposta.

Comment: Agora sim boa resposta, +1